# Get height of div dependent on text inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV with some text inside. But the height of the DIV starts at 0px, it also has an 'overflow:hidden'. After that i'm using an animation system to increase the height of the DIV. But i can't give the DIV a fixed height because the length of the text inside the DIV varies.

Is there a way to tell what the height of the DIV will be when its big enough to fit all content inside it?

Comment: Can you post de code you have so far?

Comment: The Occam's razor in me wants to know why you have `overflow:hidden` if you want to show all of the contents. Maybe you meant `max-height` or something?

Comment: overflow: hidden will hide the content that is overflowed when the height is set to 0

Comment: @MrLister Overflow hidden hides all the text inside the div, so that it won't be visib;e when the div's height is smaller then the actual content inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

Put the text inside another DIV like...

```
<div>
   <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Then animate the outer div (which as an hidden overflow) according to the height of the inner div (which has not an hidden overflow).

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the right idea, but you can't just grab the contents of the original div. What if it has padding, font-size declarations, etc? The OP needs to make an exact clone of the div -- classes, inline styles, etc.

Comment: Actually, this idea works perfectly for me. I'm not using jQuery (but Sencha Touch2) so unfortunately i can't use any of the jQuery answers. I was able to get the height of each DIV in my list.

Comment: @maxedison: my answer was assuming a change in the DOM structure, not doing it on the fly!

Answer (score 6):

I have done a horrible hack but see if this is good enough.
Basically you get the content height by setting the height to auto, then resetting it to zero and finally using your animation function, like this :

```
var tempHeight = $(".sample").css({"height" : "auto"}).height();
$(".sample").css({"height" : "0px"}).animate({
    height : tempHeight
},1000);
```

Where `.sample` is the reference to the div with the variable text content. Check out the demo for a better understanding.

**Pure Javascript Version :**

```
document.getElementById("sample").style.height = "auto"; //The id of this div is 'sample'
var tempheight = document.getElementById("sample").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("sample").style.height = "0px";
/*
Custom Animation function, Use tempheight to get the full content
*/
```

**[DEMO For The Jquery Version](http://jsfiddle.net/XQmnk/1/)**

Comment: Looks good, but unfortunately i can't use jQuery in this case :( I'm stuck with the terrible Sencha Touch library. But nice example anyway, +1 for that.

Comment: Bah.. Child's play. Look at the update and see if it works :)

Comment: Yes that's actually what i already did. Like Mike said, i had to use an inner div with auto height. I got the height of that DIV exactly as you have, that was the easy part. But thanks anywway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing/using you don't need to know the height because setting it to "auto" will ensure it expands to fill the content.

However, you could also not set the heights to 0 until you know the height by using javascript to get it. For example in jQuery:

```
$("div").each(function()
{

  $(this).attr("data-height", $(this).height()).css({"height": "0", "overflow": "hidden");

});
```

Now each div has an attribute called "data-height" that has the value of it's original height. You can then use this to expand the div when you need to.

Comment: Not setting the heights to 0 will probably result in bad user experience -- they'll all be viewable until the DOM has fully loaded, at which point the JS will hide them. Also, if the user is using jQuery (not specified in the post or tags, i know), there is an animation bug that can occur when animating the height to the value of `auto`. Perhaps that's the source of the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

Just before animating the showing of the div, clone the div and get rid of the `height:0px` constraint (change the height to auto, for example). Then grab the height of that cloned div for use in your animation.

In jQuery, this would look something like:

```
var myDiv = $('div');
var myDivClone = div.clone().insertAfter(myDiv).css('height','auto');
var myDivHeight = myDivClone.outerHeight();
myDivClone.remove();
myDiv.animate({height: myDivHeight}, 250);
```

Note the importance of actually *cloning* the element in question as opposed to just creating a new one and filling it with the same contents. You need to recreate the element exactly (other than the height modification you do afterwards), including classes, etc.

**ALSO** note the importance of injecting it into the DOM immediately after `myDiv`. This is so that the same CSS will affect it as affects `myDiv` at time of height calculation. The only potential exception to this is if you're using a `:last-child` selector in your CSS, and the clone ends up becoming the last child of the parent element. But that kind of issue should be easy enough to get around.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight || el.scrollWidth > el.offsetWidth)
{
    //keep making element bigger
    el.style.height = parseInt(el.style.height) + 2 + "px"
}
```

You could stick this snippet inside some sort of recursive function or while loop.  Essentially you are checking to see if there is more content outside of the viewable area that a scroll-bar would show.

Comment: In my experience, `scrollHeight` and `offsetHeight` have substantial differences between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

how about dropping the text in a off screen div first and getting the dimensions from that?